# 70's science fiction cartoon about human farmers settling an alien planet

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I'm trying to find the name of a science fiction cartoon from the late 1970s. It featured a human family of farmers who settled on an alien planet.

They were laughed at by the native population as they (the aliens) did everything with machinery. However they became popular and the native ruler became jealous.

Comment: Do you remember whether the film had speech? And if so, was it a "real" language or an invented one?

Comment: Was this a 'one off' feature length cartoon or was it in episodes like a TV series?